# Is supercooling water reversible?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, water, phase-transition, reversibility, ice

Water can exist in a [supercooled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercooling) state. Even at $-48,3$ degrees Celsius it can be liquid. Below that temperature, the water will freeze. If I cool the ice to, say, $-60$ degrees and heat it slowly back up again will it melt again at $-48,3$ degrees? In other words, is supercooling reversible?

Answer (score 2):

Ice carries no "memory" of the circumstances under which it first froze, which could alter the manner in which it subsequently thaws. So there is no hysteresis in the sense you mention here.

In a previous lifetime I had to deal with water that refused to freeze at 0C and most of my working career was spent ensuring that water would not boil until it hit 280C. In retrospect, water is weird stuff- just not quite as weird as what you are asking about.

Comment: So water cannot refuse to thaw at zero Celcius (as it can refuse to freeze at zero Celcius)? But instead, thaw at subzero.